# Anonymous method as parameter to BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods, begininvoke

Why can't you pass an anonymous method as a parameter to the `BeginInvoke` method? I have the following code:

```cs
private delegate void CfgMnMnuDlg(DIServer svr);
private void ConfigureMainMenu(DIServer server,)
{
    MenuStrip mnMnu = PresenterView.MainMenu;
    if (mnMnu.InvokeRequired)
    {
        mnMnu.BeginInvoke((CfgMnMnuDlg)ConfigureMainMenu, 
                            new object[] { server});
    }
    else
    {
        // Do actual work here
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid declaring the delegate.  Why can't I write something like the below instead?  Or can I, and I just can't figure out the correct syntax? The below currently generates an:

> Argument type 'Anonymous method' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Delegate'

Ok, that's right of course, but is there some other syntax I can use to do this (avoid having to declare a separate delegate in order to use `BeginInvoke()`?

(Being able to do this would fit in neatly with the concept of using anon methods/lamdas in place of explicit delegates which works so cleanly everywhere else.)

```cs
private void ConfigureMainMenu(DIServer server,)
{
    MenuStrip mnMnu = PresenterView.MainMenu;
    if (mnMnu.InvokeRequired)
    {
        mnMnu.BeginInvoke(  //  pass anonymous method instead ?
             delegate(DIServer svr) { ConfigureMainMenu(server);},     
             new object[] { server});
    }
    else
    {
        // Do actual work here
    }
}
```

Comment: Good related post: https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/control-invoke-and-begininvoke-using-lamba-and-anonymous-delegates/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
control.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { /* method details */ });
```

Or:

```cs
private void ConfigureMainMenu(DIServer server)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(new Action<DIServer >(ConfigureMainMenu), server);
    }
    else
    {
        /* do work */
    }
}
```

Or:

```cs
private void ConfigureMainMenu(DIServer server)
{
    MenuStrip mnMnu = PresenterView.MainMenu;
    if (mnMnu.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Private variable
        _methodInvoker = new MethodInvoker((Action)(() => ConfigureMainMenu(server)));
        _methodInvoker.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(ProcessEnded), null); // Call _methodInvoker.EndInvoke in ProcessEnded
    }
    else
    {
        /* do work */
    }
}
```

Comment: what library is MethodInvoker from? using System.?

Comment: @ilitirit:  That compiles ok, but only if I include method params in the call:
mnMnu.BeginInvoke( (MethodInvoker)delegate(DIServer svr) { ConfigureMainMenu(server);}, new object[] { server});

So now I am passing the method parameter "server" twice.. Once inside of the anon method, and once in object[] param to Begin Invoke... Hows that working ?

Comment: @apandit: System.Windows.Forms 


@Charles: You will pass it "twice" no matter which method you use because of the delegate invocation.

Comment: @Ilitrit,  Thanks, Action<param> () worked great for my delegate instances that take only one parameter, and after some research, I now know that Action<>() in CLR 3.x also exists in versions that take 2,3, parameters, etc... Very kewl.. This particular gig is still using CLR 2.0, but 80% of the delegates I am using take only 1 param...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to write something like this:

```
private void ConfigureMainMenu(DIServer server,)
{
    MenuStrip mnMnu = PresenterView.MainMenu;
    if (mnMnu.InvokeRequired)
    {
        mnMnu.BeginInvoke(new Action<DIServer>(ConfigureMainMenu), 
                            new object[] { server});
    }
    else
    {
        // Do actual work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method that would wrap anonymous methods, and even take care of the `InvokeRequired` semantics:

```
public static void InvokeAction(this Control ctl, Action a)
{
    if (!ctl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        a();
    }
    else
    {
        ctl.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(a));
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do:

```
control.InvokeAction(delegate() { ConfigureMainMenu(server); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single method by calling invoking yourself:

```
  ClassData updData =  new ClassData();

  this.BeginInvoke(new Action<ClassData>(FillCurve),
                           new object[] { updData });
```

...

```
public void FillCurve(ClassData updData)
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a bunch of different methods but none work. ie...

```
// Fails -- cannot convert lamda to System.Delegate
mnMnu.BeginInvoke( (DIServer svr)=> {ConfigureMainMenu(server);}, new object[] server);
// Fails -- cannot convert anonymous method to System.Delegate
mnMnu.BeginInvoke( new delegate(DIServer svr){ConfigureMainMenu(server);}, new object[] server);
```

So, the short answer is no. You could create short helper delegates in the given context and use lambdas to make it a bit neater but that's pretty much it.

EDIT: Turns out I'm wrong. The methodinvoker answer below works.
See this [page](http://www.csharper.net/blog/methodinvoker___anonymous_methods___teh_r0x0r.aspx)

Comment: ah well, thanks for trying... not a big deal, just thought this "ought" to be possible... it would fit in with the concept of using anon methods/ lamdas in place of explicit delegates that works so cleanly everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For completely anonymous methods with a limited number of parameters:

```
Func<int, int?> caller = new Func<int, int?>((int param1) =>
   {
      return null;
   });

caller.BeginInvoke(7, new AsyncCallback((IAsyncResult ar) =>
{
   AsyncResult result = (AsyncResult)ar;
   Func<int, int?> action = (Func<int, int?>)result.AsyncDelegate;
   action.EndInvoke(ar);
}), null);
```

You can use one of the other Func delegate types as needed.